# What is the proper way to dynamically add CSS or JS using ClientDependency Framework?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, client-dependency

I'm sorry to say, but the documentation is somewhat lacking here: https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/wiki/Webforms

I'm trying to register a dependency dynamically and cannot get the syntax right:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CD" Namespace="ClientDependency.Core.Controls" Assembly="ClientDependency.Core" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["AAPGmobile"] != null && Request.Cookies["AAPGmobile"].Value == "Mobile")
        {
            //mobile
            ClientDependencyLoader.RegisterDependency("~/Style/mobile.css",ClientDependencyType.Css);
        }
        else
        {
            //desktop
            ClientDependencyLoader.RegisterDependency("~/Style/desktop.css",ClientDependencyType.Css);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Document HEAD:

```
<CD:ClientDependencyLoader runat="server" id="Loader" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="CssPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="JavaScriptPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I also tried using this, but got an error:

```
bool successfullyCreated;
var loader = ClientDependencyLoader.TryCreate(this.Page, out successfullyCreated);
```

And this, but got a different error:

```
var loader = ClientDependencyLoader.GetInstance(currentHttpContext);
```

Please help with the syntax or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found that seems to work – I'm posting it here in case anyone else runs into a similar situation:

For CSS:

```
ClientDependencyLoader.Instance.RegisterDependency("~/Style/mobile.css",ClientDependency.Core.ClientDependencyType.Css);
```

For JS:

```
ClientDependencyLoader.Instance.RegisterDependency("~/Style/mobile.js",ClientDependency.Core.ClientDependencyType.Javascript);
```

Please notice, I'm not trying to create or reference an existing Loader separately, the syntax takes care of it.

The solution is adapted from code on this page: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/35307-Using-ClientDependency-Framework-from-a-Razor-Macro

Hope this helps somebody!